# Using Generic T of Method to create new instance of another object with the same Generic T

Tags: c#, generics

So I have a method which looks something like this

```cs
public void Register<T>(TimeSpan interval, ILogger logger) where T : ISchedule
{
    _schedules.Add(new Schedule<T>(interval, logger));
}
```

I want to create a new Schedule with the T provided to the Register Method.

```cs
internal class Schedule<T> : IDisposable where T : ISchedule, new() {}
```

Here I get the following error:
`'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Schedule<T>'`

Is this behavior even possible or is there anything I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply the `where T : ISchedule, new()` constraint you specified on the `Schedule<T>` class to the `Register` method as well:

```
public void Register<T>(TimeSpan interval, ILogger logger) where T : ISchedule, new()
{
    _schedules.Add(new Schedule<T>(interval, logger));
}
```

---

Consider the following two classes which implement the `ISchedule` interface.

```
public class Schedule1 : ISchedule
{
    public Schedule1() { }
}

public class Schedule2 : ISchedule
{
    public Schedule2(string foo) { }
}
```

The `Schedule<T>` class has a generic type constraint `where T : ISchedule, new()` meaning only those types implementing `ISchedule` and **containing a parameterless constructor** can be used as the type parameter. Therefore, it is illegal to specify a `Schedule<Schedule2>` since `Schedule2` does not contain a parameterless constructor.

If we do not apply the same type constraint to the `Register` method, we can call that method with both `Schedule1` and `Schedule2`. As `Schedule2` does not conform to `Schedule<T>`'s type constraint, we now have a problem (`'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Schedule<T>'`) that can be solved by applying the same constraint of `Schedule<T>` to the `Register` method.

---

Further reading: [Constraints on Type Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) on Microsoft Docs.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there any why I need to do this? Since I never actually do new T() in this method?

Comment: @Twenty please see whether the edited answer helps to understand why we need to repeat the constraint.